# copy or add command not executed on docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

This dockerfile works as expected on my laptop. But it fails if I use automated builds on docker hub.

```
FROM ubuntu
# Install required software via apt and pip
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    awscli \
    python \
    python-pip \
    software-properties-common \
 && add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa \
 && apt-get -y update \
 && apt-get install -y \
    gdal-bin \
 && pip install boto3

# Copy Build Thumbnail script to Docker image and add execute permissions
COPY build-thumbnails.py build-thumbnails.py

RUN chmod +x build-thumbnails.py
```

The error is:

```
Step 6/7 : COPY build-thumbnails.py build-thumbnails.py
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder259560514/build-thumbnails.py: no such file or directory
```

The repo is here...
https://github.com/shantanuo/docker/blob/master/batch/Dockerfile

Why would copy or add command not work for automated builds?

Comment: Sounds like the build context is different between Docker hub & your local environment. Does the automated build have a root directory that is not `batch`? In other words - do you pass the path to your `Dockerfile`

Comment: Can you please show the build configurations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like other people have had the same issue see here:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-build-failing-on-docker-hub/76191/2

> The solution is to set the build context appropriately so that the relative path >in the Dockerfile COPY is correct.
>
> In your Docker Hub repository go to “Builds” and click on “Configure Automated >Builds”. There you can set the “Build Context” for each build rule.

Check the last answer on this page too:
https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/811

Let me know if that helps!